# what does the intensity channel of a point cloud refer to?

Tags: ros, rviz, messages, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the rviz wiki, it seems intensity is related to colour? What type of information is encoded in the intensity of a point in a point cloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11020/what-does-the-intensity-channel-of-a-point-cloud-refer-to?/) by [diannay](https://answers.ros.org/users/745/diannay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is typically a sensor-dependent "brightness" of return, representing some quality of measurement: energy returned, pixel value, etc.  Sometimes it can look like a greyscale brightness.  See the [images on the right here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrating%20the%20PR2#pr2_calibration.2BAC8-SubTutorials.2BAC8-Capture_Data.Capturing_Large_Checkerboards) to view some images produced by a laser scanner returning intensities.

Just be aware that sometimes it isn't human color dependent.  Some materials reflect IR laser beams very well but appear black to our eyes.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6